# Add url to OHAttributedLabel but shouldFollowLink delegate is not called

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I add URL to attributed string in OHAttributedLabel  ("forgot password" link to www.xxx.com ") .  Everything looks perfect except that when I clicked on that string , nothing happen.

It should open that URL in safari.   And then when I tried to add delegate method.

```
-(BOOL)attributedLabel:(OHAttributedLabel*)attributedLabel shouldFollowLink:(NSTextCheckingResult*)linkInfo
```

This delegate method is not called at all.  The delegate is set properly because I tried another delegate method and it is working

```
  -(UIColor*)attributedLabel:(OHAttributedLabel*)attributedLabel colorForLink:(NSTextCheckingResult*)linkInfo underlineStyle:(int32_t*)underlineStyle;
```

I setup UILabel via Interface builder and change its class to OHAtrributedLabel. And here is my code

```
  //forgotLabel.text is "Forgot Password"
   NSMutableAttributedString *attr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:forgotLabel.text];

     [attr setLink:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"] range:NSMakeRange(0, attr.length)];

    //forgotLabel is OHAttributedLabel 
  forgotLabel.attributedText = attr
  forgotLabel.delegate = self;
```

Can somebody help ? I don't want to use TTTAttributedLabel because in my project I used OHAttributedLabel in tablecell and it work perfectly. So I don't want to add another 3rd part compnonent that does almost exactly the same thing .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this myself by adding

```
   forgotLabel.catchTouchesOnLinksOnTouchBegan = YES;
```